# Can I eat the rabbits my cat catches?

Tags: hunting, rabbits

My cat gets a rabbit every other week or so. He usually eats the whole thing himself but I was wondering if I should try and cook it for myself. Is there even enough meat on them to make it worth the effort? If I had to guess they probably weigh about 1lbs (cat weighs 15lbs). Would it be legal in the state of Washington?

[image: boots]

Comment: If you don't get a proper answer here, you can try later at [Cooking.SE]

Comment: Is this purely about the legal issue, or are you asking about health concerns as well?

Comment: @chrisdrhjh Many people in the world have actually trained their animals to do exactly this to help supplement their food. It used to be more common to use hawks, as hawks are good hunters with excellent eye sight; that you have probably seen in movies before. Also, some people train their dogs to do this. Unfortunately, our cats only bring mice and bats. They have dropped them on us while we're sleeping too. Disturbing.

Comment: Please don't try to answer in comments.

Comment: Can you eat something caught by a wild being? [Sure.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXuqJ4c1dxE)

Comment: Unrelated, but perhaps your cat should wear a bell. It probably also catches (rare) birds.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/can-wild-rabbits-be-eaten-in-the-summer-or-is-the-risk-of-disease-too-high

Comment: Super cute rabbit. Had to say it, sorry.

Comment: We have a cat that started bringing in larger and larger animals this year. He has gotten rabbits like you picture. Last night, he brought home a full grown rabbit as big as himself! It made me think of this old question, so I had to come here and mention it. When we let him spend as much time outside as he wants, he brings home enough meat that he could keep him and I both fed if I were to eat it. Hunter cats are the new contestant on the list of top 10 things you want in a survival situation.

Comment: What kind of rabbit is this? Its ears are so small.

Comment: @zundi But it's the cat's nature.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Can I eat the rabbits my cat catches?

The short answer is **yes**, but most people would not.

Our cat would do the same thing as yours, when we lived in the country. Sometimes the rabbit was just as big as the cat. We never cooked our cats kills, but I know neighbors who did and they generally made a type of rabbit stew out of them. There are lots of recipes on the internet for rabbit stew like [here](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/rabbit_stew_with_mushrooms/), [here](https://honest-food.net/german-rabbit-stew/) and [here](https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/old-fashion-rabbit-stew-86093). I recommend using lots of vegetables in the stew. It makes it seem tastier, at least to me.

And yes rabbit stew tastes excellent. That I have eaten.

If the rabbits are quite small you can always put them in your freezer until you have enough for a banquet!

It would seem legal as your cat killed its own prey out of instinct and  I truly doubt you trained it to kill rabbits. Our cat more often than not brought them home and put her kills at the front door as trying to say: "look what I brought home!"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85167/discussion-on-answer-by-ken-graham-can-i-eat-the-rabbits-my-cat-catches).

Answer (score 48):

Based on several sources related to parasites that can be found in rabbit meat, as noted in other answers in this post, it is difficult to correctly diagnose whether a rabbit has been infected or not without using a microscope of tissue samples during necropsy. That also includes the following worm types: ringworm (see [Dermatophytosis](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/exotic-and-laboratory-animals/rabbits/bacterial-and-mycotic-diseases-of-rabbits)); [trichinosis](https://honest-food.net/on-trichinosis-in-wild-game/); [larval worms, or tapeworms](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/exotic-and-laboratory-animals/rabbits/parasitic-diseases-of-rabbits); [pinworms](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/exotic-and-laboratory-animals/rabbits/parasitic-diseases-of-rabbits); and [roundworm](https://www.ag.ndsu.edu/pubs/ansci/animpest/v1227.pdf).

While those particular worms can be located in either the liver, intestines, colon, and/or feces (as either eggs, larva or adult worms), they can infect other organs (such as roundworms migrating to the brain or eyes of a host, or ringworm appearing on the skin) making diagnosis via visual indicators difficult without transmission should proper PPE not be used.

Other parasites/bacteria/diseases of rabbits include, but are not limited to: [coccidiosis (two different types); walking dandruff ("can cause mild dermatitis"); encephalitozoonosis](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/exotic-and-laboratory-animals/rabbits/parasitic-diseases-of-rabbits); and, most notably, tularemia.

When preparing a rabbit for consumption, it is recommended that you wear gloves and proper clothing since [tularemia](https://huntfish.mdc.mo.gov/hunting-trapping/species/rabbit/rabbit-safety-health) can be transmitted through contact of the skin, especially blood. (Several sources include: [link1](http://www.idph.state.il.us/public/hb/hbtulare.htm) [link2](https://www.motherearthnews.com/nature-and-environment/rabbit-fever-zmaz87mazgoe) [link3](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/generalized-conditions/tularemia/overview-of-tularemia) [link4](https://healthfully.com/dangers-eating-wild-rabbit-8459597.html) [link5](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/exotic-and-laboratory-animals/rabbits/bacterial-and-mycotic-diseases-of-rabbits)). While indication of tularemia in rabbit meat can be seen in the liver, it is recommended that you cook the meat to a min. [160 F / 72°C if cooked from fresh.](http://www.idph.state.il.us/about/fdd/fdd_fs_wild_game.htm). Cooking the meat to that internal temperature can also deal with internal worms (though it is recommended that you remove the intestines, taking care not to damage or rupture the organ in the process).

Note: Given that some of these infections can be transmitted to other animals, such as cats, take care to keep up with regular vet checks to monitor and maintain the health of your cat.

Comment: The title of the question asks "Can I eat it?" This seems like a valid answer to that question, despite the other comments. However, I think more information about the specks is in order, which AnonyTech says is being looked for. Specifically, would cooking remove the harm of the specks, or are the specks some form of contamination that cooking does not fix? (ie: Are the specks the parasites themselves, such that cooking kills them, and if so, would the dead parasites be safe?)

Comment: Wouldn't this apply for (most) wild animals?

Comment: Very good information! Thank you, I have to echo what Peter Mortensen says though, wouldn't this be the same with all wild game? I think my cat is probably due for a vet visit because I'm sure eating any meat raw is more risky than cooked.

Comment: Despite the name ringworm is fungi, not a parasitic worm.

Comment: [Myxomatosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myxomatosis) is a disease that is specific to rabbits, and probably irrelevant to humans, but I'd still avoid eating an obviously infected rabbit.

Answer (score 24):

### TLDR

- Wear gloves!
- Discard the rabbit if there are white spots on the liver
- Use a meat thermometer and make sure your meat is cooked through to 165 F / 74 C.

---

My copy of Joy of Cooking contains this advice about small game (of which rabbit is an example)

> - Never handle any wild meat without gloves because of the danger of tularemia infection
> - Always make sure the meat of wild animals is sufficiently cooked because any warm-blooded animal may be harboring trichinosis

[Tularemia](https://www.cdc.gov/tularemia/index.html), sometimes called rabbit fever, is a bacterial disease which spreads through skin contact, but is killed by [heat above 160 F / 71 C](https://www.outdoorhub.com/how-to/2013/02/25/rabbit-hunters-take-note-steps-to-avoid-tularemia/).

[Missouri Department of Conservation](https://huntfish.mdc.mo.gov/hunting-trapping/species/rabbit/rabbit-safety-health) suggests looking for symptoms of tularemia on the liver of the rabbit

> While eviscerating the rabbit, check the liver for numerous white
>   lesions about the size of a pin head. If you find these, the rabbit
>   should be discarded and not eaten.

[Trichinosis](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/trichinellosis/prevent.html) is caused by roundworms and is also killed by heat above 160 F / 71 C.

I have not been able to find any other disease risks online specifically for rabbits, but other general advice meat safety advice from [Disease Prevention for Hunters](https://www.avma.org/public/Health/Pages/Disease-Precautions-for-Hunters.aspx) includes:

> - If there are any old wounds on the carcass, and especially if there is pus present, meat in this area should be removed and discarded. A
>     large area of tissue around the wound and pus pockets should also be
>     cut away with the wound, even if the tissue looks normal, because it
>     can still harbor infection.
> - If any abnormalities are seen in the chest or abdominal cavity of the carcass, consider disposing of the entire carcass.
> - If any of the intestines have an abnormal smell or discharge, or if pockets of blood are seen in the muscle unassociated with the
>     bullet/shot/arrow wound, the flesh should be considered unfit for
>     eating.
> - The abdominal cavity should be cleaned, dried and cooled until the meat is processed. During warm weather (over 65° F, or 18.3 C), bags
>     of ice should be placed in the body cavity to hasten cooling. The
>     carcass should be protected against flies.
> - Any uncooked game should be promptly frozen, refrigerated or disposed of properly.

Comment: "During warm weather (over 65° F, or 18.3 C), bags of ice should be placed in the body cavity to hasten cooling." - this is the main point for me. You *can't* perform this step with game your cat brings you - you don't have any way to know how long ago it was caught.

Answer (score 9):

As for the legality of it, be sure to check with your local authorities. A man in Texas got a visit from a game warden for illegally taking wildlife when a dove flew into his window. [Texas Monthly](https://www.texasmonthly.com/food/dont-eat-the-birds-that-fly-into-your-window/) Washington state hunting guidelines state that pygmy rabbit hunting is [closed](https://wdfw.wa.gov/hunting/smallgame_trapping/), and they are a [threatened species](https://wdfw.wa.gov/publications/00275/) so please do be careful in this respect.

Comment: Good answer, and looking at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmy_rabbit) that might be a pygmy rabbit