# How to tell the difference between a pika and a cottontail rabbit?

Tags: animal-identification, rabbits

Some users [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20865/can-i-eat-the-rabbits-my-cat-catches) seem to think that the animal in question is a pika and not a cottontail rabbit.

How would one tell the difference between a pika and a cottontail rabbit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pika)

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:American_pika_(ochotona_princeps)_with_a_mouthful_of_flowers.jpg)

- **Rounded ears**
- **No tail**
- Short limbs
- Lives at high elevations, commonly **above or around treeline**
- Makes chirping noises.
- Protected species

[Eastern cottontail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_cottontail)

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sylvilagus_floridanus_14136.JPG)

- **Large hind feet**
- **Long ears**
- Powerful rear legs
- White **underpatch underneath of the body**
- Lives in meadows and forests
- Common game animal

The animal in the other question has long ears, a visible tail, a white under patch and is in an area inhabited by humans, clearly making it a rabbit.

Comment: See this new answer and my comment https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20893/4079 More research might be required.

Comment: @JamesJenkins The specific species wouldn't change that its a rabbit and not a pika

Comment: Is the question now, "Should you eat a Pika to get rid of the evidence that your cat killed one?"